# $(\frac{1}{\kappa})^2+(\frac{\dot{\kappa}}{\kappa^2\tau})^2=r^2$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, self-learning

Show that for a curve lying on a sphere of radius r with nowhere vanishing torsion, the following equation is satisfied:

$$\left(\frac{1}{\kappa}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\dot{\kappa}}{\kappa^2\tau}\right)^2=r^2$$

Please help me doing this. Honestly, I could not do anything. So I cannot show my efforts. Thank you.

Comment: An old differential geometry exercise whose solution had appeared on the Internet multiple times, e.g.  here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198119/prove-that-a-curve-is-spherical-iff-it-satisfies-the-relation

Comment: The question you sent its link and my question are not same:( @francis

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand the question you sent. It is to complecated. :( @Francis

Comment: Using notations in another [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/532080/59379), you have: $$\begin{array}{rl}
\vec{t}\cdot(\vec{\gamma} - \vec{\alpha}) & = 0\\
\vec{n}\cdot(\vec{\gamma} - \vec{\alpha}) & = -\frac{1}{\kappa}\\
\vec{b}\cdot(\vec{\gamma} - \vec{\alpha}) & = \frac{\dot{\kappa}}{\tau\kappa^2}
\end{array}$$

Comment: Two conditions are actually equivalent, you should see that by taking derivative on both sides of your equation using chain rule.

Comment: I am confused too much. So sorry. I am grateful of you if someone Will solve this. By using both question, it is impossible to solve this question. Because I am a newlearner @achillehui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to illustrate the relationship between two question: write $\rho=1/\kappa$ and $\sigma=1/\tau$. We have $$\rho^\prime=\left(\frac{1}{\kappa}\right)^\prime=-\frac{k^\prime}{k^2}.$$ Your equation thus becomes $$\rho^2+(\rho^\prime\sigma)^2=r^2.$$ Take derivative on both side, we get $$2\rho\rho^\prime+2(\rho^\prime\sigma)(\rho^{\prime\prime}\sigma+\rho^\prime\sigma^\prime)=0,$$ manipulate the terms few time we have $$\frac{\rho}{\sigma}+(\rho^{\prime\prime}\sigma+\rho^\prime\sigma^\prime)=\frac{\rho}{\sigma}+(\rho^\prime\sigma)^\prime=0,$$ which is equivalent to the equation in the link.

**Remark:**

Judging by your question you actually want to go from a spherical curve to its condition. Here is a hint on how to start: consider a unit-speed curve $\alpha$ lies on a sphere with center $\mathbf{c}$ and radius $r$. (since an arbitrary-speed curve involves only reparameterization, the result here can be extended.) We can thus write $$(\alpha-\mathbf{c})\cdot(\alpha-\mathbf{c})=r^2.$$ Take derivative on both side, $$2(\alpha-\mathbf{c})^\prime\cdot(\alpha-\mathbf{c})=0.$$ Recall that $T=(\alpha-\mathbf{c})^\prime$, so $$T\cdot(\alpha-\mathbf{c})=0.$$ Keep on this track and utilize different Frenet formula, you will eventually get to the desired result.

Comment: Hmm, I guess, from here, I will continue to solve in the link begining from the line "Now, we go the other direction, so assume". Isnt it?

Comment: @B11b: Not really, see my updated answer.